# Diference betwen def and val in particular case

Tags: scala

suppose I have the following type defined.

```
type T[+A] = M => (A, M)
```

What is the difference between

```
val fun: T[Int] = _.nextInt
```

and

```
def fun: T[Int] = _.nextInt
```

where `nextInt` takes `M` to `(Int, M)`?